# Add references to PresentationCore.dll and PresentationFramework.dll in .NET API

Tags: .net, winforms, .net-5

I'm trying to reference PresentationCore.dll and PresentationFramework.dll in .NET 5 API but apparently it requires also WindowsBase, this is the error I get:

> "System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Windows.DependencyObject' from assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'."

If I try to add reference to Windows.Base, it shows error in Visual Studio:

[image: e]

Comment: [and -windows after net5.0 targetframework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64788670/1466046) and and entry `UseWPF` this adds all WPF references.

Comment: I've tried changing the project to: <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows7.0</TargetFramework> but it still shows the same error, it doesn't allow me to add windows.base.dll. I take it from here: C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\Windows.Base.dll

Comment: you don't need to add anything, after changing targetframework and adding UseWPF, the reference is already added

Comment: Thank you, @magicandre1981!!! I've added this: <UseWPF>true</UseWPF> to the csproj PropertyGroup section and it worked !

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer, so that you can [accept my reply as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to "close" the question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What you want to do is to add a WPF reference. This is not required if your csproj includes the `net5.0-windows` entry for `TargetFramework` and `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

This `UseWPF` entry automatically adds all WPF references and you can use WPF calls.