# How to set RenderOptions globally in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, image

i had problems with pixelated images and found later that `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"`
solves the problem. Is there a way to set this globally instead of adding the code to each individual image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set it from a globally applicable style:

```xml
<Application x:Class="SO_72015119.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Image}}">
            <Setter Property="RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode" Value="HighQuality" />
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: This just causes an Exception at runtime for me about not being able to find System.Windows.Controls.Image.

Comment: @Double_A It's unrelated, maybe try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67298609