# How to use Media Player in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, media-player, visual-studio-2022, windows-media-player

The documentation only lists the code for launching the player:

```
MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer;
System.Uri manifestUri = new Uri('http://amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/49b57c87-f5f3-48b3-ba22-c55cfdffa9cb/Sintel.ism/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl)');
mediaPlayerElement.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(manifestUri);
mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Play();
```

I was smart enough to copy and paste it, but the MediaPlayer class was not found. The IDE suggests importing System.Windows.Media. I select this item, but the import did not occur. I myself try to add using System.Windows.Media, but it doesn't find it.

In WindowsForms, I added a MediaPlayer element to the Toolbox, but it didn't appear in the list. Appears only if all elements are displayed, then it will appear and be gray (inactive).

I just started learning Visual Studio and so far I am completely at a loss from what is happening. I looked in NuGet, there is no MediaPlayer, I didn’t find anywhere on the Internet how to connect it, everywhere they only write code and how to add the MediaPlayer element to the element panel.

When installing Visual Studio 2022, I only chose the development package with Windows Form for Windows. .NET 6.0 platform. The target OS is Windows 7, I'm using it.

Comment: Add a reference to the **PresentationCore.dll** assembly and then add `using System.Windows.Media;` to the top of your **.cs** file.

Comment: @MickyD Thanks to you came to this answer, not sure if this solution is correct but it seems to help... I didn't understand to add a reference to PresentationCore.dll, so I used this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67504550/10946427

Comment: @Dmitry The Form,cs toolbox still doesn't show the MediaPlayer, but I added it